# Why is this TextView null?

Tags: java, android, service

So I'm trying to update a textview from another class. However,whenever I'm calling the method, It seems the textview is null?

I have no idea why that would be the case.

Here is the relevant code

MediaPlayerService:

```
@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        UI = new MediaPlayerUI();
        mp.start();
            int minutesDuration = mp.getDuration() / 6000;
            int secondsDuration = (mp.getDuration() % 6000) / 1000;
            UI.setDurationText(minutesDuration,secondsDuration);
            UI.setProgressBarVisibility(0);
            UI.setPauseButtonVisibility(1);
            UI.playback();

    }
```

MediaPlayerUI:

```
public class MediaPlayerUI extends MediaPlayerFragment {


public MediaPlayerUI(){

}
public void setSeekBarProgress(int position){
    seekBar.setProgress(position);
}
public void setSeekBarMax(int max){
    seekBar.setMax(max);
}

public int getSeekBarProgress(){
    return seekBar.getProgress();
}

public void setDurationText(int minutes, int seconds){

}

public void setProgressBarVisibility(int code){
    if(code == 0){
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
    }else{
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void setPauseButtonVisibility(int code){
    if(code == 0){
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

MediaPlayerFragment:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_media_player, container, false);
    mSeriesImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.series_image);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
    playButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
    pauseButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
    messageTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_title);
    seriesTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.series_name);
    mProgressText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.progress_text);
    mDurationText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.duration_text);
    mNoAudioText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.no_audio_text);



    mNoAudioText.setVisibility(v.GONE);
    playButton.setVisibility(v.GONE);
    pauseButton.setVisibility(v.GONE);

    mAudioURL = getArguments().getString(Keys.AUDIO_URL_KEY);
    mModel = getArguments().getParcelable(Keys.INTENT_SERIES_MODEL_OBJECT_KEY);
    mPosition = getArguments().getInt(Keys.POSTION_KEY);
    messageTitle.setText(mModel.getmMessageTitle().get(mPosition));
    seriesTitle.setText(mModel.getmSeriesName());


    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MediaPlayerService.class);
    intent.putExtra(Keys.INTENT_SERIES_MODEL_OBJECT_KEY,mModel);
    intent.putExtra(Keys.POSTION_KEY,mPosition);
    intent.putExtra(Keys.AUDIO_URL_KEY,mAudioURL);
    getActivity().bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    seekBar.setEnabled(true);

    return v;
}
public void setDurationTextView(int minutes,int seconds){
    Log.i(TAG,"mDurationText...."+mDurationText);

}
```

Log Output:

```
10-29 20:25:00.091 26349-26349/com.tubbs.citychurchob   I/MediaPlayerFragment: mDurationText....null
```

Also, if I call the method directly inside MediaPlayerFragment, the method does NOT return a null value.

I'm really just shooting in the dark on how to update the UI from a Service so any helpful advice on that would be great also. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not guaranteed that the TextView is already created or not when you are calling setDurationText().

In that case you can register a broadcast receiver in your fragment and then send broadcast from the service

```
 IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
 intentFilter.addAction("update_media_ui"); 
 updateMediaUiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Get the data here and then set the text if 
                // the TextView is not null or save the data first 
                // and set it later if the TextView is null.
            }
        };
 registerReceiver(updateMediaUiReceiver, intentFilter);
```

and then you also need to unregister the receiver in Fragment onDestroy()

```
unregisterReceiver(updateMediaUiReceiver);
```

This is how to send broadcast from service

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction("update_media_ui");
this.sendBroadcast(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: Why is that though? Does it discard the textview once I start a service? It seems I cannot call any method from another class regarding textviews and they not be null. Also, wouldn't the textview still be null?

Comment: Sure, I just did. I just took out the method as I was trying something else.  All the views in MediaPlayerFragment are null if I even try to do outside of the fragment.

Comment: @MrTimotheos try to override onCreateView() on MediaPlayerUI and the return super(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

Comment: where should I put the intent filter? Inside onCreateView?

Comment: @MrTimotheos Hmmm so that's not the problem them. Yes you can add it inside onCreateView but looks like the root of the problem is different thing. But you can give it a shot

Comment: @MrTimotheos You are welcome! Maybe you could vote and marked the answer as correct so people with same problem as you can try this answer too :)